# Angle between the normal of a origin-centered semiellipse in a point P and the x axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I use a software called Substance Designer which has a Pixel Processor where I can assign to every pixel of a image a gray-scale value defined by a series of operations.

I am basically trying to generate a ["normal gradient"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhYa.jpg) generated by the normals of a semi-ellipse with a given **a** and **b** semi-major and semi-minor axis.

This semi ellipse is **origin-centered ** and has the principle axes parallel to the x and y axes.

For all points P(x,y) with y≥0, I want to find the angle or direction θ of the outwards-facing ellipse normal that intersects that point. Both when a>b and if possible when b>a "

[Here is a visual representation of what I am after, although I only need the values for y>0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7x1.jpg)

[I am trying to visualize the blue tangents on the evolute when y> 0. All the points on the same normal will have the same value.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Evolute1.gif)

Thanks

Comment: Please draw a figure.  Your explanation is ungrammatical and unclear.

Comment: I am doing it right now :)

Comment: Then you *MUST* state that the principle axes are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes!!!!

Comment: You are completely right, let me add it to the text and thanks for your patience David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extended comment, to solve the following problem that came up in the comments:

We have an axis-aligned ellipse, centered at origin, width $2$, height $2 h$ — so semi-major axis is $1$ and on $x$ axis, and semi-minor axis is $h$ and on $y$ axis, with $0 \lt h \lt 1$.  For all points $(x, y)$ on or outside the ellipse, $x \gt 0$, $y \gt 0$, we want to find the direction (angle or slope) of the ellipse normal that passes through that point.

The eccentricity $\epsilon$ of this ellipse is
$$\epsilon = \sqrt{1 - h^2} \quad \iff \quad h = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}$$

Using angle parameter $\varphi$ the points on the ellipse can be parametrized as
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_{\varphi}(\varphi) &= \cos\varphi \\
y_{\varphi}(\varphi) &= h \sin\varphi \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
The slope of the normal is
$$m = \frac{ -\frac{d x_\varphi(\varphi)}{d \varphi} }{ \frac{d y_\varphi(\varphi)}{d \varphi} } = \frac{1}{h}\tan\varphi$$
Solving for $\varphi$ we find
$$\varphi = \arctan\left(m h\right)$$
and reparametrizing the points on the ellipse (in the positive quadrant, $x \gt 0$, $y \gt 0$), we get
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\displaystyle x_m(m) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + h^2 m^2}} \\
\displaystyle y_m(m) &= \frac{h^2 m}{\sqrt{1 + h^2 m^2 }} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
The points on the normal are on a line $y = m x + y_0$, i.e.
$$y_m(m) = m x_m(m) + y_0(m)$$
and rearranging and simplifying, we find that
$$y_0(m) = \frac{(h^2 - 1) m}{\sqrt{1 + h^2 m^2}}$$
If point $(x, y)$ is on the normal with slope $m$, it too fulfills the equation:
$$y = m x + y_0(m) = m x + m \frac{h^2 - 1}{\sqrt{h^2 m^2 + 1}}$$
To solve this for $m$ (remembering that $\theta = \arctan m$) we need to solve a quadric equation:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \left( h^2 x^2 \right) & m^4 \\
+ \left( - 2 h^2 x y \right) & m^3 \\
+ \left( x^2 - h^4 + h^2 y^2 + 2 h^2 - 1 \right) & m^2 \\
+ \left( - 2 x y \right) & m \\
+ \left( y^2 \right) & ~ = 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$
This has zero to four real roots $m$. At and outside the ellipse, at $x \gt 0$, $y \gt 0$, there is exactly one real root (because the normals for the positive quadrant only intersect at $y \le 0$).

Unfortunately, there is no simple algebraic expression for the solutions $m$ that fulfill above.

For what it is worth, Maple suggests the following operations to find the four candidate real roots:

```
t36 = x * x
t33 = y * y
t43 = h * h
t47 = t43 * t43
t48 = t43 * t47
t83 = (t48 + t43) * t36
t32 = t33 * t33
t82 = 3 * t32
t81 = 3 * t33
t26 = 3 * t36
t80 = -3 * t47
t79 = 6 * t48
t49 = t47 * t47
t78 = -3 * t49
t77 = 3 * t49
t74 = -18 * t47
t73 = 12 * t48
t24 = t43 * t33
t64 = t47 - 2 * t43 + 1
t16 = -t24 - t36 + t64
t65 = t47 * t36
t17 = t65 * t82
t35 = t36 * t36
t67 = t43 * t35
t18 = t67 * t81
t21 = t32 * t80
t22 = 3 * t24
t57 = y * t33
t31 = t57 * t57
t23 = t48 * t31
t25 = -3 * t35
t51 = t48 * t48
t28 = t43 * t51
t30 = t43 * t49
t54 = x * t36
t34 = t54 * t54
t45 = cbrt(-1 + 6 * t67 + 18 * t65 - 15 * t47 + 20 * t48 - 15 * t49 - t51 + 6 * t43 + 6 * t30 + t34 + t21 + t22 + t23 + t25 + t26 + t17 + t18 + t36 * t77 + t32 * t78 + t32 * t79 + t35 * t80 + t30 * t81 + 6 * y * sqrt(3 * t17 + 3 * t18 + 3 * t21 + 3 * t22 + 3 * t23 + 3 * t25 + 24 * t28 - 84 * t51 + 168 * t48 - 84 * t47 + 24 * t43 - 3 * t49^2 - 3 + (-2 * t31 - 70) * t77 + 3 * t64 * t34 + 3 * (t31 + 56) * t30 + 3 * (t78 + t73 + t74 + 12 * t43) * t35 + (-3 * t51 + 12 * t30 - 18 * t49 + t73) * t82 + (3 * t28 - 18 * t51 + 45 * t30 - 60 * t49 + 45 * t48 + t74 + (3 * t48 - 6 * t47) * t35 + 21 * (t30 - 4 * t49 + t79 - 4 * t47 + t43) * t36) * t81 + (3 + 3 * t51 - 18 * t30 + 45 * t49 - 60 * t48 + 45 * t47 - 18 * t43 + (t77 - 6 * t48) * t32) * t26) * h * x + (48 * t83 - 12 * t49 - 12 * t47 - 96 * t65 + 18 * t48) * t33 - 12 * t83)
t68 = t16 * t16 / t45
t46 = sqrt((t33 + ((2 * t16) + t45 + t68) / (3 * t43)) / t36)
t66 = t16 / t43
t71 = y / x
t72 = (2 * t71 / t43 + (t66 * y + t57) / t54) / t46
t19 = t71 / 2
t70 = t19 + t46 / 2
t69 = t19 - t46 / 2
t60 = (2 * t33 - ((t45 + t68)/t43 - 4 * t66) / 3) / t36
t62 = sqrt(t60 - 2 * t72) / 2
t61 = sqrt(t60 + 2 * t72) / 2
m1 = t70 + t61
m2 = t70 - t61
m3 = t69 + t62
m4 = t69 - t62
```

Above, `cbrt(...)` is the cube root operation (same as `pow(..., 1.0/3.0)`), and `sqrt(...)` is the square root operation.  If the argument of the square root is negative (but note that it could be *effectively zero*, due to rounding errors and such, even if strictly speaking negative; you should round those to positive zero instead), then those candidate solutions do not exist.  Remember that you do still need to verify that $m \gt 0$, to get the desired result, $\theta = \arctan m$.

(Also remember that if $y = 0$ and $x \gt 0$, then $\theta = 0$; if $y \gt 0$ and $x = 0$, then $\theta = 90^o$.  The rest of the quadrants are symmetric.)

Because of this, it might be worth the effort to consider *approximations* to the problem; for example, instead of a real ellipse, consider approximating the ellipse using one or two cubic polynomials (perhaps with four cubic Bézier curves).  Cubic approximations should yield at least two significant digits of precision (less than 1% of error), and would definitely suffice for human perception and "visual arts".  I am not sure if that approach yields any better answers, but it would be the avenue I would explore next.

Comment: Thanks for all the time you spent on helping me AC!

Comment: I was hoping to eliminate the problem of calculating if a point belongs to a normal to the ellipse or not by considering that for every point there is one ellipse passing for it which is axis-aligned and origin centered and which has the same eccentricity ϵ.

Comment: I have been looking into 3 point arches and 5 point arches as valid approximations :).

Comment: I also tried to implement the Maple solution but I am afraid it is a bit too advanced for my skills :D

Comment: This might be of help! Is there any way to find the equation of the blue lines (tangentian angle) per y>= 0 for the ellipse evolute (mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseEvolute.html)? It seems exactly what I need   –

Comment: @Paolo_G: If one creates an axis-aligned ellipse centered at origin with eccentricity $\epsilon$, wider than it is tall, so that it passes through point $(x,y)$, the ellipse normal at that point has angle $\theta$,$$\theta(x,y) = \operatorname{atan2}\left(y, (1 - \epsilon^2) x\right)$$If this helps, I can show its derivation too; it is quite straightforward.

Comment: Forgot: If the ellipse is taller than it is wide, then$$\theta(x,y) = \operatorname{atan2}\left((1 - \epsilon^2) y, x\right)$$.

Comment: Hi AC. I tried θ(x,y)=atan2(y,(1−ϵ2)x) in the software but it does not produce the angle to the normals to the ellipse sadly And I finally understood why it does not work (took me a while to wrap my head around it I apologize, you have tried to tell me all the way since the beginning). Yes, you are completely right the only way to create the gradient I need is solving that scary quadric equation which is a dead end. That's a bit depressing. I was really hoping for a way out but sometimes there are not any. Thanks for all the help anyway!

Comment: @Paolo_G: No worries!  Yes, the fourth-degree equation is truly annoying, and pops up whenever ellipses are involved -- for example, finding the (minimum) distance between a point and an ellipse.  I'll take a look at a couple of approximations I know of, to see if any of them help.  If I find anything useful at all, I'll add another answer here.

Comment: I would love to try it yes! An approximation might work well for visual arts :)

Answer (score 1):

This figure may help those who wish to solve this problem:

[image]

By the way, here are three origin-centered ellipses with the same eccentricity $e=2$ that go through the same point, so if the OP wants a *unique* and hence solvable problem, it should be restated as I have, above.

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for helping out :) I really appreciate any help I can get! Yes this is exactly what I am after, although the red point P should be on the Ellipse to be absolutely precise. The function should work for every point of the plane.

Comment: (@Paolo_G):  Huh??  You wrote "for any point P(x, y) in the Cartesian plane."  No *hint* there that it must be on the ellipse.  I of course shows a *general* case for $P$.  So what do you mean?

Comment: Sure, let me explain, I wrote: the ellipse centered in the origin, which is passing for the same point P and which has a known eccentricity "e", That means that the ellipse passes for the point P. Apologies if it was not clear! :)

Comment: @Paolo_G:  Your comment specification is unclear and non constraining.  There are infinitely many origin-centered ellipse of specified eccentricity $e$ that pass through any given point.  See why?

Comment: Thanks David, as you can see geometry is not my specialty. I thought there was one origin centered ellipse passing for P which has a given eccentricity. e= sqrt (1- (b/a)(b-a))

Comment: But I definitively should have specified that the axis of the ellipse are parallel to the x and y axis

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarifying the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Consider an axis-aligned ellipse centered at origin, height $2$ (semimajor axis $1$), width $2\chi$ (semiminor axis $\chi \lt 1$), parametrized using angle variable $\varphi$:
$$\vec{p}(\varphi) = \left [ \begin{matrix} p_x(\varphi) \\ p_y(\varphi) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} \chi \cos \varphi \\ \sin\varphi \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{1}\label{EQ1}$$
The eccentricity $\epsilon$ of this ellipse is
$$\epsilon = \sqrt{1 - \chi^2} \quad \iff \quad \chi = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} \tag{2}\label{EQ2}$$
The tangent vector $\vec{t}(\varphi)$ is
$$\vec{t}(\varphi) = \nabla\vec{p}(\varphi) = \left [ \begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{d p_x(\varphi)}{d \varphi} \\
\displaystyle \frac{d p_y(\varphi)}{d \varphi} \\
\end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix}
t_x(\varphi) \\ t_y(\varphi) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} - \chi \sin \varphi \\ \cos \varphi \end{matrix} \right ]\tag{3}\label{EQ3}$$
The normal vector $\vec{n}(\varphi)$ is the tangent vector rotated $90^o$ clockwise (since the angle parameter traverses the ellipse counterclockwise):
$$\vec{n}(\varphi) = \left [ \begin{matrix} t_y(\varphi) \\ -t_x(\varphi) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} n_x(\varphi) \\ n_y(\varphi) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} \cos\varphi \\ \chi\sin\varphi \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{4}\label{EQ4}$$
The angle $\vec{n}(\varphi)$ makes with the $x$ axis with $0^o \le \varphi \le 180^o$ is $\theta$,
$$\theta = \operatorname{arctan}\left( \frac{n_y(\varphi)}{n_x(\varphi)} \right) = \operatorname{arctan}\left( \chi \frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi} \right)  = \operatorname{arctan}\left(\chi \tan\varphi\right)$$

This means that for an axis-aligned ellipse that is taller than it is wide, the relationship between the angle parameter $\varphi$ and the angle between the ellipse normal and the positive $x$ axis $\theta$ is
$$\theta = \operatorname{arctan}\left(\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} \tan\varphi\right) \tag{5a}\label{EQ5a}$$
and conversely (by solving above for $\varphi$),
$$\varphi = \operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}\tan\theta\right)\tag{5b}\label{EQ5b}$$

---

This same ellipse also fulfills
$$\frac{x^2}{\chi^2} + \frac{y^2}{1^2} = 1$$
which we can solve for $y$:
$$y(x) = \pm \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{\chi^2}} = \pm\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{1 - \epsilon^2}}$$
Since $\eqref{EQ1}$ says that $x = \chi\cos\varphi$, the angle parameter $\varphi$ is
$$\varphi = \operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{x}{\chi}\right)  = \operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}}\right)$$
and the angle $\theta$ relationship to parameter $\varphi$ simplifies to
$$\theta = \operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1 - \epsilon^2 - x^2}{1 - \epsilon^2}}\right)$$
in the positive quadrant ($x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$).

Comment: Thanks AC! :D This is simply amazing! If it does not bother you I have a follow up question: the software I use for visually rapresenting functions (substance designer) can calculate acos, asin and atan2 but not arctan sadly. Is there anyway to express the answer so I can calculate θ using one of them?

Comment: Sure. $\operatorname{arctan}(y/x) = \operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$, and $\operatorname{arctan}(x)=\operatorname{atan2}(x,1)$.  So, you can use$$\theta = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\tan\varphi, 1\right)$$and$$\theta = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2-x^2},x \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\right)$$ for example.

Comment: First of all thanks again for the help you are giving me! Secondly, I tried to visualize the second option you gave me in Substance Designer but is giving me a odd result: the software will visualize a function assigning to each pixel the value of the angle θ. Technically, it should create something similar to an angular gradient, where all the points on the same normal share the same gray-scale value equal to the measure of the angle θ. But what I am getting is different, it is a linear gradient parallel to the y axis. I'd love to show you I can't figure out how to share pics in a comment :/

Comment: The second is only valid for points $y = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2/\epsilon^2}$.  What you want, is a function $\theta(x, y)$, describing the angle of the normal that passes through point $(y, x)$.  This function is really only defined at and outside the ellipse, because inside the ellipse each point $(x, y)$ is crossed by many normals.

Comment: Yes it makes total sense that inside the ellipse it would not work. I only need to visualize it outside the ellipse it in fact :)

Comment: But the visualization is not showing correctly and this is odd. I am sure I am doing something wrong. It should definitively not look like a vertical gradient.

Comment: It looks like a vertical gradient, because each row of pixels has the $\theta$ that the ellipse intersecting that row has.

Comment: The problem with $\theta(x,y)$ is essentially solving $$\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{1 - \epsilon^2}{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2 + (\tan\theta)^2}} + r \cos \theta = x \\ \displaystyle \frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2 + (\tan\theta)^2}} + r \sin \theta = y\\ \end{cases}$$ for $\theta$ and $r$ (although you don't need $r$, the distance from the ellipse), and I'm not sure if this has algebraic solutions (i.e., a simple function of form $\theta(x, y) = \dots$).

Comment: I understand :), yes the r value is not important. I was looking for a function which would return the same value for all points belonging to the normal line in any point P (knowing that inside the ellipse it would be defined). Something similar to atan2(x,y), but that instead of giving the angle to xy, gives me the angle of the normal to the ellipse.

Comment: I made this picture to show exactly what I am after.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7x1.jpg

Comment: And this too https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhYa.jpg

Comment: @Paolo_G: Yes, $\theta$ in the pair of equations in my above comment is exactly that for every point $(x, y)$ on or outside the ellipse, assuming an axis-aligned ellipse centered at origin, with height $2$ (taller than it is wide) and eccentricity $\epsilon$ (and thus width $2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$.  Essentially, point $(x, y)$ is at distance $r$ from the ellipse, and the normal to the ellipse that passes through that point has direction $\theta$.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to express that in any better/more useful form!

Comment: I would recommend you create a new question, something like *"I have an axis-aligned ellipse, with height $2$ (semimajor axis $1$ parallel to $y$ axis), and width $2 \chi \lt 2$ (semiminor axis $\chi \lt 1$ parallel to $x$ axis).  For points $(x,y)$ on and outside the ellipse, I want to find the angle or direction $\theta$ of the outwards-facing ellipse normal that intersects that point."*

Comment: Yes! I will do this, thanks for being so helpful AC!. I was wondering, since I only need the result for half the ellipse, I think it may be possible to calculate the results for the inside top half of the ellipse without them hitting themselves ( it seemsto me like all the points of intersections happen on the lower half i.stack.imgur.com/6jhYa.jpg).

Comment: Would this work in your opinion? : "I have an axis-aligned  origin-centered semi ellipse with center in the origin, 
with height a (semimajor axis 1 parallel to y axis), and width 2b (semiminor axis χ). For points (x,y) with x≥0 and y≥0, I want to find the angle or direction θ of the outwards-facing ellipse normal that intersects that point. Both if a>b and b>a"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhYa.jpg